# how to highlight a editing row in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, highlight

I want to highlight a active row, if I am editing any cell in a row.
When I search, I see highlighting a row with value of a cell using conditional format. But I want to highlight current active row.

Comment: You need VBA for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/highlight-the-active-cell-row-or-column

Comment: You could do it indirectly using formulas: `=(("")=(),("")=())` but you'd need to press `F9` (recalculate) to activate the formula calculation

Answer (score 0):

Set the conditional formatting formula to `=CELL("row") = CELL("row", A1)`, assuming `A1` is the top left cell in the range you are trying to format. As P.b. mentioned, this still requires recalculation to take effect.